# Let $n=p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_k^{a_k}$ where the $p_i$ are distinct primes. Then $F(n)=\prod_{i=1}^{k} (1+f(p_i)+f(p_i^2)+\cdots+f(p_i^{a_i}))$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions

Let $f$ be a multiplicative function and $F$ be its summatory function. Let $n=p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_k^{a_k}$ where the $p_i$ are distinct primes. Then 
$$F(n)=\prod_{i=1}^{k} (1+f(p_i)+f(p_i^2)+\cdots+f(p_i^{a_i}))$$

I know  I can split apart $f$ since its multiplicative but other then that I'm not sure what to do I haven't worked with product sums before.

Comment: Do you mean $n=p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_k^{a_k}$ instead of $n=p_1^{a1}\cdots p_k^{ak}$?

Comment: The first one I'll fix it now

Answer (score 1):

What happens with $F$ if $n$ is a prime power, say $p^m$? What are divisors of $p^m$? Surely only powers of $p$ that are not greater than $m$. Therefore $F(p^m) = \Sigma_{i=0}^{m}f(p^i)$, which is exactly one of factors in your product. As $f$ is multiplicative, you can combine what you've got for every prime divisor of $n$ to see general form of $F$.